# How to show apt history via CLI on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, apt-get

Is there any way I can check the package management history with apt or apt-get on Ubuntu? I mean, I know there is some way to do this using yum on RedHat distribution with `yum history` and also this allow us to do a rollback on certain installation with `yum history undo <ID of the package>`.

Is there something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi :) Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/how-do-i-show-apt-get-package-management-history-via-command-line

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the logs

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It did help me a lot!